# How to rename columns with Pandas? Object has no attribute error when using rename

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rename

I am trying to write a simple code in Python3 that takes all xls files in a folder, converts all text to uppercase, combines all the files into one file and save as an xlsx file. This all works. However, I also want to alter the names of the header row using rename.  I can't get the code to rename anything I get the following error message:

data.rename(columns={'A 1': 'A1',
AttributeError: 'ExcelFile' object has no attribute 'rename'

Anyone help please? Thanks.

This is my code so far:

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob(r'C:\\Test\\*.xls'):
   df = pd.read_excel(f)
   df = df.applymap(lambda s:s.upper() if type(s) == str else s)
   all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\\Test\\alldata.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
all_data.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
print("All data in upload folder combined into one file")
files = glob.glob(r'C:\\Test\\*.xls')
for f in files:
  os.remove(f)
data = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\\Test\\alldata.xlsx')
data.rename(columns={'A 1': 'A1',
                'A 2': 'B1',
                'A 3: 'C1',
                }, inplace=True)
data.ExcelFile.save
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try **read_excel** and **to_excel** instead of pd.ExcelFile and data.ExcelFile.save respectively. In the code you upload you have also forget the single quote after the 'A:3'. Here is an example:

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
data.rename(columns={'A 1': 'A1',
                'A 2': 'B1',
                'A 3': 'C1',
                }, inplace=True)
data.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```